# Want Mathematica (instead of CDF Player) to launch by default when accessing .nb files over the Web

Tags: download, file-association, mathematica, mathematica-notebook

I have both *Mathematica* and CDF Player installed on my machine. I'm trying to access a *Mathematica* notebook over the Web and want *Mathematica* to launch when clicking on the link.

Instead, the file is rendered in the browser through the CDF player and I can't figured out how to save the file and open it in *Mathematica*.

Any ideas anyone? Ideally I would like *Mathematica* to launch by default when accessing .nb files over the Web and have CDF player launch only if *Mathematica* were not installed.

Comment: Operating system ? Does the page at the URL about:plugins (in your web browser) mentions CDF player (or Mathematica) ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5 and Safari 6.0.5. The installed plugins list mentions both Mathematica and CDF Player.

Comment: You probably can disable the CDF player and the Mathematica plugin in a preference dialog somewhere in Safari. (Causing Mathematica-the-real-program to be an option in an hypothetical "Open with" dialog -- not sure as I don't own a Mac).

Comment: Thank you. Ideally I'd rather not disable the plugins because I would still like the CDF player when accessing cdf files. My ideal scenario would be for the browser to: - launch Mathematica when detecting a .nb file - launch the CDF player when detecting a .cdf file. At the moment the browser is not smart enough to distinguish between the two and launch CDF player in both cases

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about Apple OS X and Safari than about _Mathematica_. The question should be asked on Ask Differently.

Comment: Super question - am having the same problem. And a pain in the butt it is too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for superuser, as it relates specifically to the application _Mathematica_ and the design of the default settings for the Wolfram CDF plug-in. The question should be asked on mathematica.SE.